# Partial Extract from Database Table with Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a large database table with an auto-incrementing integer primary key and I'm using Spring Batch to create an extract of the table every day for use by other systems.

I am using the approach of persisting the highest id put in the previous extract to use to set the start point of the next extract (i.e. in sql where id > last_id_extracted). I am currently doing this using JDBC to a next_id table using plain old Java.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of extract boundaries with Spring Batch. Presumably this is a pretty common scenario in batch processing and Spring Batch can help?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're solution is perfectly fine if no other party can insert items in your db.

Answer (score 3):

Your method works only in a narrow sense of what could happen to your data. It does not take deletions and modifications of the existing data into account.

To make it more robust, add another table to serve as the Extract Status, with the record ID of the data table as a foreign key. The Extract Status table should have Last Exported On date stamp if and when a record is uploaded. Then you can implement the following rules:

1) if there is no corresponding row in Exp Stat, export
2) if the last updated on > last exported on, export it
3) if it exists in Exp Status table but not in Data Table, send a delete message to the consumers.